# Parallel image comparison function keeps increasing memory

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing, parallelization, memory

I have written the following code to align two arbitrary images:

```mathematica
fastAlign[i1_, i2_] := 
  Block[{transform, f, finv, w1, w2, h1, h2, tmp1, tmp2, result},
   transform = 
    Quiet@FindGeometricTransform[i1, i2, Method -> "RANSAC", 
      TransformationClass -> "Affine"];
   If[Head[transform] === FindGeometricTransform, Return[{}]];
   f = Last@transform; finv = InverseFunction[f];
   {w1, h1} = ImageDimensions[i1];
   {w2, h2} = ImageDimensions[i2];
   tmp1 = 
    ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i2, f, DataRange -> Full, 
     PlotRange -> Sort /@ Transpose[{f[{0, 0}], f[{w2, h2}]}]];
   tmp2 = 
    ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i1, finv, DataRange -> Full, 
     PlotRange -> Sort /@ Transpose[{finv[{0, 0}], finv[{w1, h1}]}]];
   result = {ImageCompose[tmp1, {ColorNegate@i1, 0.5}, 
      Round@({w1, h1}/2) - f[{0, 0}]], 
     ImageCompose[tmp2, {ColorNegate@i2, 0.5}, 
      Round@({w2, h2}/2) - finv[{0, 0}]]};
   Clear[transform, tmp1, tmp2];
   Return[result]
   ];
```

This will output something like:

[image: two aligned crops of a picture of a tiger]

Clearly showing which regions of the two images overlap. Pretty nifty I thought.

However, when applying the code in parallel to a moderately sized list of potential image pairs (`Length[correlationlist] = 4801`), Mathematica's memory usage steadily keeps increasing until I max out my RAM (32 GB). I also sometimes get `General::nomem` warnings, so that the operation actually doesn't complete. I am looking for suggestions to reduce the memory load. For information: my input images are preloaded and rescaled to 480 pixels, so are relatively small. I expect that my final table will be around 50 items.

```mathematica
images = ParallelMap[Import, filelist];
imagessmall = ParallelMap[ImageResize[#, 480] &, images];
correlationlist = {{1,5},{6,11},...};

ParallelTable[
 If[(r = 
     fastAlign[imagessmall[[pair[[1]]]], 
      imagessmall[[pair[[2]]]]]) != {},
  Join[r, pair],
  Nothing
  ]
 , {pair, correlationlist}
 ]
```

Comment: Can you move your `Import` and `ImageResize` commands to be inside the `ParallelTable` expression?  The point being that having all the images in main memory in the main kernel and then transferring them to the other kernel for computation, it's the data transfer that takes the memory and time.

Comment: I tried this just now, but it does not really seem to help. The memory still gets maxed out. Maybe because I now have to call `filelist[[pair[[1]]]]` and this symbol still takes up memory in all kernels?

Comment: @Tanatomanic You should rewrite your code so that each image is only imported once and only into the parallel core where it will be processed.

Comment: @JasonB. @AlexeyPopkov, this works, thank you! So my immediate problem is solved. However, the downside is when I need to compare one image with multiple others (i.e. `{1,5},{1,8},...`) because then the image needs to be reloaded every time. I guess there is no way around that?

Comment: I can only suggest trying [`ResourceFunction["ImageRead"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ImageRead) instead of `Import` for better performance.